# How to make couple of lists from a main list with condition

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

I have this input:

```
my_list = [
    0, 'root', 'disable', 'dynamic', 'pages', 'login', 'sensitive', 'registration', 'screen', 'flag_secure', 'application', 'frida', 'blurring', 'instrumentation', 'mechanism', 'recent', 'debugger', 'information', 'restrict', 'stronger', 'anti', 'capture', 'appsview', 'strengthen', 'code', 'data', 'exported', 'use', 'protection', 'default', 'ensure', 'hide', 'improve', 'runtime', 'copy', 'paste', 'expired', 'impelement', 'frequency', 'adding', 'feature', 'instrument', 'attempts', 'avoid', 'escape', 'authentication', 'encryption', 'components', 'device', 'char', 'verification', 
    1, 'detection', 'frequency', 'dynamic', 'emulator', 'encoding', 'encrypt', 'encryption', 'ensure', 'escape', 'expired', 'exported', 'feature', 'flag_secure', 'frame', 'frida', 'device', 'generated', 'hardcoding', 'headers', 'hide', 'impelement', 'implement', 'improve', 'information', 'input', 'instrument', 'instrumentation', 'integrity', 'disable', 'version', 'verification', 'char', 'access', 'adding', 'alert', 'anti', 'application', 'appsview', 'array', 'attempts', 'authentication', 'avoid', 'blurring', 'capture', 'character', 'default', 'check', 'code', 'come', 'components', 
    2, 'implement', 'version', 'frequency', 'dynamic', 'emulator', 'encoding', 'encrypt', 'encryption', 'ensure', 'escape', 'expired', 'exported', 'feature', 'flag_secure', 'frame', 'frida', 'device', 'generated', 'hardcoding', 'headers', 'hide', 'impelement', 'improve', 'information', 'input', 'instrument', 'instrumentation', 'integrity', 'disable', 'detection', 'verification', 'char', 'access', 'adding', 'alert', 'anti', 'application', 'appsview', 'array', 'attempts', 'authentication', 'avoid', 'blurring', 'capture', 'character', 'default', 'check', 'code', 'come', 'components', 
    3, 'access', 'version', 'frequency', 'dynamic', 'emulator', 'encoding', 'encrypt', 'encryption', 'ensure', 'escape', 'expired', 'exported', 'feature', 'flag_secure', 'frame', 'frida', 'device', 'generated', 'hardcoding', 'headers', 'hide', 'impelement', 'implement', 'improve', 'information', 'input', 'instrument', 'instrumentation', 'integrity', 'disable', 'detection', 'verification', 'default', 'adding', 'alert', 'anti', 'application', 'appsview', 'array', 'attempts', 'authentication', 'avoid', 'blurring', 'capture', 'char', 'character', 'check', 'code', 'come', 'components'
]
```

From this list, how can I make a couple of new lists for each integer in the list, and append the string element in each of the new lists?

For example, the new list should contain a first integer (i.e. 0 or 1 or 2 or 3), and a dozen of string elements before the next integer in list.

This is kind of what I would like to get as result:

```
List0 = [0, 'root', 'disable', 'dynamic', 'pages', 'login', 'sensitive', 'registration', 'screen', 'flag_secure', 'application', 'frida', 'blurring', 'instrumentation', 'mechanism', 'recent', 'debugger', 'information', 'restrict', 'stronger', 'anti', 'capture', 'appsview', 'strengthen', 'code', 'data', 'exported', 'use', 'protection', 'default', 'ensure', 'hide', 'improve', 'runtime', 'copy', 'paste', 'expired', 'impelement', 'frequency', 'adding', 'feature', 'instrument', 'attempts', 'avoid', 'escape', 'authentication', 'encryption', 'components', 'device', 'char', 'verification']`

List1 = [1, 'detection', 'frequency', 'dynamic', 'emulator', 'encoding', 'encrypt', 'encryption', 'ensure', 'escape', 'expired', 'exported', 'feature', 'flag_secure', 'frame', 'frida', 'device', 'generated', 'hardcoding', 'headers', 'hide', 'impelement', 'implement', 'improve', 'information', 'input', 'instrument', 'instrumentation', 'integrity', 'disable', 'version', 'verification', 'char', 'access', 'adding', 'alert', 'anti', 'application', 'appsview', 'array', 'attempts', 'authentication', 'avoid', 'blurring', 'capture', 'character', 'default', 'check', 'code', 'come', 'components']`

# ...etc
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: You don't want to make a separate lists, you want to make list of lists, trust me. Iterate over list, check `isinstance(element, int)` and initialize new sublist if condition passed or add to current if not.

Answer (score 0):

You can locate the indexes where integers occur in your list. Add to this the "index" *beyond* the list, i.e. the list's length. These represent the cutting points to get out the chunks you need.

Using `zip` you can combine start/end ranges of these chunks and use those to slice the list accordingly:

```
cuts = [i for i, val in enumerate(my_list) if isinstance(val, int)] + [len(my_list)]
result = [my_list[i:j] for i, j in zip(cuts, cuts[1:])]
```

The result will be a list of lists. You can print each list like this:

```
for lst in result:
    print(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish one list with dozen lists inside:

```py
def iter_and_pack_by_number(lst):
    answer = []
    values = []
    for index in range(len(lst)):
        if (isinstance(lst[index], int)) and index != 0:
            answer.append(values)
            values = []
        values.append(lst[index])
    
    return answer
```

See [result](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/4R1Re6C)